# Audio only works after plugging and then unplugging headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, headphones

**I'm using ubuntu server 16.04**

I used `amixer -D pulse sset Master 75%` to set my volume high. 
I then played some test audio and didn't get any audio output from my tv (plugged in through hdmi). I then plugged my headphones into my computer and played the test audio again, it worked. Once it worked I unplugged my headphones and then play the test audio an the audio played through my tv. Once I reboot I must repeat the process in order to play sound through my tv.

How can I permanently set my tv to play audio through my hdmi port on my tv without having to unplug my headphones in and out of my computer every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ubuntu tools that are provided for configuring the sound devices.  The gui tools are called **Sound** with is already installed by default, and **Pulse Audio Volume Control** which can be installed from the repository.

```
$ sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Open the **Pulse Audio Volume Control** app.  From the **Output Devices** tab check the desired device that is providing sound by noticing the visual slider showing the output.  Click on the **Configuration** tab and set the profile for the one that is working, by choosing from the options available in the drop-down.

Now go into the built in **Sound** apt, and match the same output device there.

When you had completed the match and settings, this should stick and survive reboots.  It's also a convenient way to check and adjust when you experience other sound issues.

Comment: I need to use a terminal. I'm doing it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just going into the **Sound** app and maybe clicking on the selected **Output** will help. I had a kind of similar issue and this solved my problem at least to some extent.